# I would like to get 4 separate prints: "This is a thread 1", "This is a thread 2" and so on

Tags: c, multithreading

pthread_create in a for loop, this is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>


pthread_mutex_t mutex;

void* helloWorld(void *i) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    printf("This is a thread %d\n", *((int*) i));
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    return 0;
}


int main() {
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    pthread_t threads[4];
    int i;
    printf("Main Message\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, helloWorld, &i);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);\
    }

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);

    return 0;
}
```

The order doesn't really matter as long as all 4 threads are working.

I've tried to use mutex but it didn't solve the issue.

My current output is pretty random, it can be 0000 or 0112 or anything else.

Comment: The problem is you are passing a pointer to i. Not the value of i. So you are printing a value which is changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is two-fold:

1. First of all you don't have control over when the threads run or in which order.
2. You pass the ***same*** pointer to all threads.

You can solve the second issue by passing the *value* if `i` to the threads. This is one of the few cases where it's considered okay to pass values instead of pointers:

```
pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, helloWorld, (void*)(uintptr_t) i);
```

Then in the thread

```
printf("This is a thread %d\n", (int)(uintptr_t) i);
```

The first issue, about the order, you have to come up with some other way to synchronize the threads and how they notify each other. For example by using  four condition signals, one for each thread, that you signal in the order you want the threads to execute.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works now! One more questions, do these threads interference one another or they work separately?

Comment: @Neya Without any synchronization they work totally independent of each other. Which might lead to problem since they all use `printf` and therefore share its buffer (there's a *data race*).